# Su/sudo not working consistently

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

I am running Debian on a Lenovo x220 and upgrade my packages quite regularly. I discovered recently a change in the way how I elevate with `sudo`. Normally I just `su` or `sudo` stuff like e.g. `arp-scan -l`.

However, not sure why, when I elevate with `sudo -s` and sometimes with `su` I occasionally get the error message, that the command is not found. Looking into the `sudoers` file (via `visudo`) does not help either way because the variables are set and have not been touched or modified. I googled a fair bit around but could not discover any solution that explains why it's working just every now and then but not consistently?

Anyone having a idea what may have been changed or altered?

//edit - documented below, I have elevated first with `sudo -s`, with which I could find the command this time. Using `sudo -i` was successful in finding/locating `arp-scan` as well. By typing `su` I was not able to run the command/find the executable.

```
nomax@debian:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for nomax: 
root@debian:/home/nomax# arp
arp              arpd             arp-fingerprint  arp-scan
root@debian:/home/nomax# exit
exit
nomax@debian:~$ sudo -i
root@debian:~# arp
arp              arpd             arp-fingerprint  arp-scan
root@debian:~# exit
logout
nomax@debian:~$ su
Password: 
root@debian:/home/nomax# arp-scan -l
bash: arp-scan: command not found
root@debian:/home/nomax# exit
exit
nomax@debian:~$ sudo -i
root@debian:~# arp-scan -l
Interface: wlp3s0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
```

Comment: Any example we can work with? A screenshot where you get "command not found" but the same command works when typed again would be great. Or at least a console dump (from a real session, not made up). Please [edit] the question to add it. For now the most plausible explanation of inconsistency is you make typos sometimes.

Comment: Note that `su` switches to the root user **and the root users path**. Those might not be the same as the path you search for as user.  Comparing those might he helpful.

Comment: Try running `which arp-scan` and `echo ${PATH}` and `whoami` and running the program by its full path.  Investigating login scripts (/etc/profile, ~/.profile, ~root/.profile) might be helpful, as might checking the log file that sudo uses ( see /var/log/*auth*log* )

Comment: Your example doesn't show that "it's working just every now and then but not consistently". It *may* be consistent: `arp-scan` works after `sudo -i`, doesn't work after `su`. Always.

Comment: Thanks for the head's up - sounds like that could explain my problem in the end. I was under the assumption that su elevates 'more' than sudo -s/-i.